# Inconsistent results from rvest::html_nodes()

Tags: r, rvest

When I run this:

```
# load required libraries
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
 
# provide sample url
url <- "https://www.thewholesaler.co.uk/cgi-bin/go.cgi?id=3074"
 
# read html
doc <- rvest::read_html(url)

# parse html 1st time
doc %>% rvest::html_nodes("meta")

# parse html 2nd time
doc %>% rvest::html_nodes("meta")
```

I get this:

```
> # parse html 1st time
> doc %>% rvest::html_nodes("meta")
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <meta name="robots" content="noindex">\n
[2] <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;URL=http://www.puckator-dropship.co.uk/gifts/\t">
> 
> # parse html 2nd time
> doc %>% rvest::html_nodes("meta")
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n
[2] <meta name="robots" content="noindex">\n
[3] <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;URL=http://www.puckator-dropship.co.uk/gifts/\t">
```

Why am I getting different results between the 1st and 2nd parsing even though the code is identical and the html doc being queried remains unchanged?

I'm running rvest v1.0.3.

Comment: This is weird!!. Whether you use `rvest::html_elements`, `rvest::html_nodes`, `xml2::xml_find_all`, they all have that strange behaviour of outputing 2 the first time, then 3 the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I think this is coming from how R caches calls. When you run `html_nodes(doc, "meta")`, I believe R is storing that in local memory (which is intertwined with XML encodings, to some degree). When you call `html_nodes(doc, "meta")` again, R decides to just read what it stored last time. However, since HTML_nodes is closely tied to XML encodings, one of the nodes - the one describing how R stored its cached version - is returned as well. This gets into how R handles pointers (objects), and how it handles memory in general. I wish I was more of an expert on this stuff, but after doing a little digging, this is the most I could distill. This is very interesting!

If you wanted, you could submit an issue to the tidyverse/rvest repository on GitHub.